# Mysql user management centralized

Tags: linux, open-source, mysql, user-management, ldap

I search software for centralized MySQL user management on linux platfrom. I want to manage multiple MySQL server (MariaDB 10+) or only users (create,remove and privileges) in one place.

At the moment I find a few software, among others : PHPMyAdmin with multiple server option, Ansible and Terraform.

I would like to find something more advanced. If there are any other solutions, I would ask for information. It can be both paid and open source software.
I wonder if it can be implemented into freeipa or LDAP.

Thanks !